# window.location in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

This is a react.js question. I have a button that I want to run a function and also go to an internal link. My question is pretty simple. If my code looks like this...

```
        <Button onClick={(e) => {settingsStateChange(); e.preventDefault(); window.location='/settingsPage';}}>
            <SettingsImg src="./img/settings.png" alt="" />
        </Button>
```

it redirects the page to localhost:3000/settingsPage which is not a valid way to navigate to this page. How does this work in react? How can I navigate here while also running other functions onClick?

Comment: If you don’t want to trigger a reload of the page (and lost all runtime state) while making change to the URL in address bar, then [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) API is what you’re looking for.

Comment: There is two parts to this: A) SPAs usually use some form of javascript router (`react-router`, `reach-router`, etc for React) these routers replace the URL in the address bar but don't actually trigger a redirect, they just let your app know that the route has changed. B) your server side (whatever it may be) will need to be able to serve your html page and assets that contain your React app at these different routes in case someone directly navigates to them. i.e. `/` and `/settingsPage` both need to serve the `index.html` page.

Comment: Usage: `history.pushState(null, "", "/settingsPage")`